# Data adapters should be mutually exclusive for handling inputs - TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I got this error

```
RuntimeError: Data adapters should be mutually exclusive for handling inputs. Found multiple adapters [<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.data_adapter.GeneratorDataAdapter'>, <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.data_adapter.CompositeTensorDataAdapter'>] to handle input: <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.iterator_ops.OwnedIterator'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

when I start training  (TensorFlow 2.2.0-rc2)

```
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=dl.length//batch_size, shuffle=True, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

and data adaptor like

```
def get_batched_dataset(self, batch_size):
    self.dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((self.filenames, self.labels))
    self.dataset = self.dataset.repeat()
    self.dataset = self.dataset.map(map_func=self._parse_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    self.dataset = self.dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)

    iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(self.dataset)
    return iterator

train_generator = dl.get_batched_dataset(batch_size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. There were columns in the train data with all zeros or all ones. So basically you have columns that are equal or are multiples of each other and thus not mutually exclusive.